# How can I handle an url route with 3 segments?

Tags: php, url-routing

I'm really bad at explaining things. Basically I'm trying to learn to develop MVC from the scratch without any frameworks.

I want to create an administrator panel and I want the Url to have categories, which would look something like:
`localhost/admin/core/settings`

As of the way MVC is set up right now, this is what I am getting, `localhost/admin/settings`.

I'm a bit confused on how I would do this.
I believe the end result of the code layout would be like:
`Controllers/Admin/Core.php`
As for the code, I'm not too sure.

index.php:

```php
<?php
    require_once('../app/bootstrap.php');

    // Init Core Library
    $init   =   new Core;
```

Core.php:

```php
<?php
    /*
     * App Core Class
     * Creates URL & loads core controller
     * URL FORMAT - /controller/method/params
     */

    class Core {
        protected $currentController    =   'Pages';
        protected $currentMethod        =   'index';
        protected $params               =   [];

        public function __construct(){
            //print_r($this->getUrl());

            $url    =   $this->getUrl();

            // Look in controllers for first value
            if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]).'.php')){
                // If exists, set as controller
                $this->currentController    =   ucwords($url[0]);
                // Unset 0 Index
                unset($url[0]);
            }

            // Require the controller
            require_once '../app/controllers/'. $this->currentController . '.php';

            // Instantiate controller class
            $this->currentController    =   new $this->currentController;

            // Check for second part of url
            if(isset($url[1])){
                // Check to see if method exists in controller
                if(method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])){
                    $this->currentMethod    =   $url[1];
                    // Unset 1 index
                    unset($url[1]);
                }
            }

            // Get params
            $this->params   =   $url ? array_values($url) : [];

            // Call a callback with array of params
            call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], $this->params);
        }

        public function getUrl(){
            if(isset($_GET['url'])){
                $url    =   rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
                $url    =   filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
                $url    =   explode('/', $url);
                return $url;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to handle routing for your solution. The best would be to create a simple router class that handles the URI routing, requests, and query strings.

This way, you can take full URI - `admin/core/settings` and call the proper Controller and Method, instead of splitting this into chunks and handling it the way you did.

The proposed solution is not the final and most ideal, but it should fit. There are better approaches using PHP namespaces that handles the loading of the files automatically.

Assuming you have added directives in .htaccess to pass the URI:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Create a class `Router` that would handle the routes and initiate the classes and call methods:

```
class Router {

    public $routes = [];

    public function __construct( $routes = [] ) {
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }


    public function load( $route ) {

        if ( in_array( $route, $this->routes ) ) {
            if ( file_exists( $this->routes[ $route ]['file'] ) ) {
                require_once $this->routes[ $route ]['file'];
                $class = new $this->routes[$route]['class'];
                call_user_func( array( $class, $this->routes[ $route ]['method'] ) );
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Then after requiring the bootstrap.php you can take the route:

```
<?php

 require_once('../app/bootstrap.php'); //require in boostrap.php router class, you could call it there
```

In the bootstrap.php:

```
 require_once('Router.php'); //require the Router class 

 //define the routes 
 $routes = [
    '/admin/core/settings' => [
       'file'   => 'Controllers/Admin/Core.php',
       'class'  => 'Core',
       'method' => 'Settings' //i.e. that you method Settings to open the settings for the admin
    ] //if you are not using namespaces
 ];
 $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  //take the URI 
 $router = new Router($routes); //instantiate the Router class 
 $router->load($uri); //handle the given uri
```

Then in the Core class, you should have method `Settings`:

```
class  Core {


    public function __construct() {

    //you could parse all requests here and pass it to the object's property to be used in other methods of the class 
    }

    public function Settings() {
        //add your code
        //handle the requests, retrieve the data via model, render the view, pass the data to the view, etc
    }
}
```

I would recommend though considering using namespaces, and autoload mechanism. See composer.org docs for this and read on php.net about the spl_autoload, spl_autoload_register and check the php-fig as well.

Composer would handle the autoloading of classes, so it instead of using `require` all the time, it would load the files automatically if all namespaces are correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will start to use namespaces.